# Cannot push grails app to heroku master - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: grails, deployment, heroku, key, push

Good Morning,

I have started deploying my grails app to Heroku.

I have been following this tutorial:

https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/12/15/grails

Everything was good until

> git push heroku master

The error occured:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Heroku needs to get your SSH public key. See [Managing your SSH Keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys).

You need to generate an SSH key, if you don't have one yet.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then, you'll need to upload this public key to heroku

```
heroku keys:add
```

Heroku can now identify you for who you are, and will allow you to push to your repository.